# Check if dictionary has no values for all keys

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best way to check if a nested dictionary has no values for all keys?

Eg:

```
dict = {
    'var1': [],
    'var2': {
        'var3': [],
        'var4': {}
    },
    'var5': {}
}
```

`bool()` returns `True` since it's not strictly an empty dict.

It's doable with recursion, but I'm curious if there are 'better' ways to do this in terms of performance as well as code length - perhaps with any package functions.

```
def get_val(d):
    val = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if (v):
            if (type(v) is dict):
                if (not get_val(v)):
                    return False
            else:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: You don't use `val`, and function name `is_empty` or `no_values` or so would be better.

Comment: Agreed, please clarify the `get_val` function name. What exactly does it determine about `d`?

Comment: Also, you need to clarify how `list`s fit into this picture. You say "nested dictionary", but a `list` is not a `dict`. You want to interpret an empty list as being an empty part of your structure?  What about lists that contain dictionaries that may or may not be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as clarification, this method works for a nested compositie `dict` / `list` structure as that is what you have shown in your example

```py
def empty(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return all(empty(sub) for _, sub in d.items())
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return all(empty(sub) for sub in d)
    return False
```

This is certainly shorter, but it is still recursive.  Delving through a arbitrarily nested structure is an inherently recursive problem.

Also, you may notice this function removes any reliance on the implicit `bool`ness of any objects. The reason being that while an empty `list` `[]`, and empty dict `{}` evaluate as false, so do other zero-like objects, e.g. `0`, `0.0`, `''`.

Comment: Thank you, good point on the zero-like objects. "Delving through a arbitrarily nested structure is an inherently recursive problem" I see now.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Heap Overflow, the `val` list is not used, and so it does not have to be declared.

I can't say this is a notable improvement over your code, but it does simplify a few things and removes syntactic sugar.

```py
def is_empty(d):
    for key, val in d.items():
        if val:
            if isinstance(val, dict):
                return is_empty(val)
            return False
    return True
```

It's good practice to simplify code by making sure your Boolean logic isn't needlessly convoluted. The snippet from your original source code is a good example.

```py
if (not get_val(v)):
    return False
```

Instead of a double negative, streamline by making everything explicit.